# Is there a safe way to do an object pool in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, pool, reference-counting

I've profiled my app and observed that an object pool would be beneficial. However, I want to make sure that I do it in a safe way that does *not* require consumers to explicitly call a `-recycle` method when they're done. The only way to do this is using retain count semantics. Here are the options I see:

- Override `-dealloc` and have it recycle itself (and not call `[super dealloc]`), as [Mike Ash does](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-12-17-custom-object-allocators-in-objective-c.html). However, the documentation says super should always be called inside `-dealloc`.
- Override `-retain` and `-release` and have it increment/decrement my own retain count variable. If it hits 0, instead of calling `-dealloc`, have it recycle itself. The documentation for these two methods says that you can do this, so I like this option. However, the documentation for `autorelease` doesn't mention anything about overriding it. Do I need to override `autorelease` as well if I do this?

Is there a safe way to do this?

Comment: Do you want it to be a non-ARC project?  I think a pool can be achieved under ARC unburdening everyone from most memory management woes.

Comment: What's expensive, the allocation or the initialization of your objects?

Comment: This object pool is for UIViews, which are expensive to create. The project would use ARC (aside from classes where I’d override a special method) although that’s not that important to this question

Comment: -dealloc is documented that way because if you forget (in non-ARC) then it is a memory leak, unless you are doing something special like you are intending :-).  I wouldn't avoid that approach for that reason.  Be sure to call objc_destructInstance(), which should clear weak references and remove associated objects.  With your second approach, the object's -dealloc will not be called, so its ivars will still be set -- may want a -prepareForReuse method.  autorelease will eventually call release so no need to override if you go that way.

Comment: OK @CarlLindberg, so I'd do it like this? https://gist.github.com/michaeleisel/c4416c836fdb355cbe10d07604d650c1

Comment: How certain are you that that's safe? Especially calling objc_destructInstance without dealloc'ing, that makes me nervous

Comment: For example, what if UIView sets an associated object inside of its init method?

Comment: Pretty sure that -dealloc is just objc_destructInstance() then freeing the object pointer.  Any ivars may still be set though.  Normally that is OK if init is called again.  You may want to reset all the ivars to zero -- i.e. memset everything, though you'd need to keep track of the class and reset the isa ivar after (object_setClass()).  I really haven't done this so not sure if any other pitfalls, but seems OK.  That is really just saving the allocation though, not the initialization, unless you are avoiding the -init calls on reuse (in which case retain/release may be a better approach).

Comment: I want to avoid -init as well. dealloc can still do the job though, no? I just avoid calling objc_destructInstance?

Comment: If you want to avoid init, I would use your second approach.  Remember by the time your -dealloc has been called, all the subclass -dealloc implementations have also been called, so many of the ivars have been removed.